# Evaluate the infinite union and infinite intersection of $\left[\dfrac{1}{n},n\right]$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> I need help evaluating the infinite union and infinite intersection of $\left[\dfrac{1}{n},n\right]$ such that $n\in\Bbb N^+$.

I've been working for hours trying to figure out how to do this and I'm still not certain I understand this, but I think I might have gotten it.

My understanding says that

- $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{n},n\right]=(0,\infty)$.
  In this case, we want to identify the largest interval which $\left[\dfrac{1}{n},n\right]$ can produce.
- $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{n},n\right]=\{1\}$. In this case, we want to identify the interval which is included in every interval that $\left[\dfrac{1}{n},n\right]$ produces.

Please tell me if my reasoning is sound and also can you show me how to justify my evaluation. My professor says that "For a complete description of the union one has to determine not only which elements are in the union but also which elements are not in the union. How one breaks into case to consider depends on the sets which one is given", and I do not understand what this means.

Thank you

Comment: You probably want to accept the given answer.

Answer (score 4):

The intersection is not $1$ but is $\{1\}$.

For proving that the union is $(0,\infty)$ you must show that for every positive $r$ we can find a positive integer that satisfies $1/n\leq r\leq n$ and secondly that $[1/n,n]\subseteq(0,\infty)$ for every positive integer $n$.

The first action shows that $(0,\infty)\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[1/n,n]$.

The second action shows that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[1/n,n]\subseteq(0,\infty)$.

---

For proving that the intersection is $\{1\}$ it is enough to prove that $1\in[1/n,n]$ for each positive integer $n$ and secondly that it is unique in having this property. This uniqueness becomes evident if you concern the case $n=1$.

The first action shows that $\{1\}\subseteq\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[1/n,n]$.

The second action shows that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[1/n,n]\subseteq\{1\}$.